# Target a html id without variable in JavaScript performance

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any reason as to not change a html element without using a variable?
For instance
`<p id="xSpdOut"></p><script> xSpdOut.innerHTML = xSpd : +shape1.xSpd;</script>` as apposed to storing the id as a variable in the script ?
`<p id="xSpdOut"></p><script> const xSpdOut = document.querySelector("#xSpdOut")xSpd; +shape1.xSpd;</script>`
I'm assuming it's performance but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you were changing the `innerHtml` as part of a button press, or part of a loop, it would be better to search for the element and save a reference to it once when the page loads, rather than searching for it again every time you click the button or go through the loop. That's the occasion that saving it as a variable makes a difference, otherwise it's just negligible.

TLDR: Searching with `query` is slow, so save in a variable if that can avoid doing searching multiple times.

Comment: Ok so if there's more then a few elements for it to handle it's worth it? Thank you!

Comment: For performance, try to reduce the number of searches (so make variables if necessary). For readability, sometimes fewer variables make fewer lines of code, but then can also obfuscate things, so it's down to how you think it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are used for ease of the programmer. So yes, you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "hello there";
```

But DON'T do:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "hello there";
document.getElementById("id").style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; background-color: 'black'";
document.getElementById("id").remove();
```

That is SLOW. Instead do:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
element.innerHTML = "hello there";
element.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; background-color: 'black'";
element.remove();
```

Which is faster in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "New text!";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="id01">Old Heading</h1>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById("id01");
element.innerHTML = "New Heading";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Both code changes the code of the h1 tag.